# Setting TextBlock Visibility on selection Change

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

Currently I have a combo box, and want to change the visibility of a TextBlock on certain selections.

Error it's producing `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
private void Selection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Findpf() == 12)
    {
        DateAutoCompleteBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        DateAutoCompleteBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Tried `= Visibility.Collapsed` also and same result. How do i fix this ?

```
public uint Findpf()
{
    if (Pf.Text == "Annual")
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (Pf.Text == "Semi-annual")
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if (Pf.Text == "Tri-Annual")
    {
        return 3;
    }
    if (Pf.Text == "Quarterly")
    {
        return 4;
    }
   if (Pf.Text == "Bi-Monthly")
    {
        return 6;
    }
     if (Pf.Text == "Monthly")
    {
         return 12;
    }
}
```

Initialization of Autocompletebox Xaml

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox x:Name="DateAutoCompleteBox" Visibility="Visible" Width="220"></telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: can you add the code for Findpf()

Comment: It just returns Integers based on the value of a Textbox but sure.

Comment: Please show the Xaml where you are creating `DateAutoCompleteBox`, specifically where you are assigning the `Name` property

Comment: And it's bounded within a stackpanel if that plays a role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this to check what value is null

```
private void Selection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(DateAutoCompleteBox == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("DateAutoCompleteBox   is null"); return;
    }
    if(Pf == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pf  is null"); return;
    }
    if(Pf.Text == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pf.Text  is null"); return;
    }
    if (Findpf() == 12)
    {
        DateAutoCompleteBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        DateAutoCompleteBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DateAutoCompleteBox is set to null and you cant access or set properties on objects that isnt initialized.